# Which extension should I use for view templates in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates

As far as I know, **.rhtml** is deprecated in Rails 2. In some guides there is only **.erb**, but both RubyMine and NetBeans IDE generate **.html.erb** and I've also seen it many people using.

I've tested both and they seem to work fine without any errors or warnings, but which one is correct? **.erb** or **.html.erb**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

file_name.`format`.`extension` is the accepted convention now, where format is html, xml, json, anything really and extension is `erb` if you're using erb, `haml` if you're using haml and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you want to have the format in the file name.